# XAML: Toggleswitch reset state

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, toggleswitch

I want to perform the following. I have a ToggleSwitch whichs Toggled event handler performs some action. If this action fails I want to reset the ToggleSwitch's state to what it was.

I achieve this by doing: `toggleSwitch.IsOn = !toggleSwitch.IsOn;`

My problem is that this again raises the Toggled event resulting in an infinit loop if the action always fails.

Here is my complete code sample

```
    private async void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleSwitch toggleSwitch = sender as ToggleSwitch;
        success = dummyService.performAction(toggleSwitch.IsOn); 
        if (!success )
        {
            //raise dialog to inform user here
            toggleSwitch.IsOn = !toggleSwitch.IsOn;
        }
    }
```

I know that this behavior is already implemented in different apps so it can't be too hard to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this detaching and reattaching your event:

```
if (!success )
{
    toggleSwitch.Toggled -= ToggleSwitch_Toggled;
    try
    {
      toggleSwitch.IsOn = !toggleSwitch.IsOn;
    }
    finally
    {
      toggleSwitch.Toggled += ToggleSwitch_Toggled;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise, sounds promising but what exactly is the yourToggledEvent.

Comment: `ToggleSwitch_Toggled` is `yourToggledEvent`.  He has you unsubscribing from the event then changing the toggle value and finally resubscribing.  This will prevent it from firing again.

Comment: I don't get you here - how do I get the event inside the ToggleSwitch_Toggled method? there are only the params object sender and RoutedEventArgs

Comment: ToggleSwitch_Toggled is. I will update my asnwer so you can understand it better.

Comment: The event `toggleSwitch.Toggled` is fired by `toggleSwitch`.  You get to assign what this event does by using the `-=` or `+=` operators as displayed in his code.

Comment: Definitely the best way of doing this. I came here to give the exact same answer. Unsubscribe from the event from within the method, change the property, then re-subscribe :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you only want to perform the operation when the `toggleswitch` is on.  If that is the case then you can try this:

```
private async void ToggleSwitch_Toggled(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleSwitch toggleSwitch = sender as ToggleSwitch;

        if(toggleSwitch == null || !toggleSwitch.IsOn)
          return;
        // You are missing your await statement....
        success = await dummyService.performAction(toggleSwitch.IsOn); 
        if (!success )
        {
            //raise dialog to inform user here
            toggleSwitch.IsOn = !toggleSwitch;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise but my action should be performed in any case

Comment: Then Giangregorio's answer is the way to go.

Comment: The event should return *void* not *Task* (this is this rare case). Have you tried to build the code?

Comment: @Romasz You should refer to [Async/Await -Best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).  I thought the same thing you did but the return types are not what they seem.

Comment: @Romasz After rereading my own link it seems you are correct in this instance.  Event handlers should have a return type void....  I will correct it.